# How to change wireframe color using GL in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created this simple script that switched the object rendering to wireframe:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class PreviewCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool Wireframe = false;

    void OnPreRender()
    {
        GL.wireframe = this.Wireframe;
    }

    void OnPostRender()
    {
        GL.wireframe = false;
    }
}
```

I attached this script to my camera and everything seems to work, but I also want to add the ability to change the color of the wireframe, but with no luck so far.

I tried using: `GL.Color(/*Some Color*/);` and `GL.Begin() and GL.End()`, maybe I just missed something, but none of it seems to do the trick.

```
void OnPreRender()
{
    GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
    GL.Color(Color.red);
    GL.wireframe = this.Wireframe;
    GL.End();
}
```

Can someone give me some advice on how can I make this work?

Comment: [This answer on the gamedev stack exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/108217/121653) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `GL.wireframe=true` vertex colors provide wireframe color and there are only two ways to change that color:

1. Set material with custom shader which replaces vertex colors and set to each object. Or manually set vertex colors in meshes. Second variant very complex for UI and other runtime generated meshes.
2. Make camera post-processing which recolor output texture to monochrome color (or by custom pattern, as you wish). You can use [CommandBuffer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.CommandBuffer.html) for this purpose.